# log4net ThreadContext default value

Tags: log4net

I'm trying to use ThreadContext to add some extra parameters into the log lines. It works fine  however when some of the parameters are not initialized log4net prints "(null)" in the output:

DEBUG|0327-133110600|CurrentAppDomainHost.ExecuteNodes|logger|(null)|(null)|(null)|127.0.0.1|(null)|test

my pattern:

%-5p|%d{MMdd-HHmmssfff}|%t|%c{2}|%X{aCode}|%X{bCode}|%X{cCode}|%X{dCode}|%X{eCode}|%m%n

is there a way to use just an empty string instead of those (null) and not setting them explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can set the following in app/web.config:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="log4net.NullText"
     value="" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: not sure if you have to use a space instead of an empty string. I did not test that. See also this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-55

Comment: or in code... log4net.Util.SystemInfo.NullText = "NULL-TEXT";
 log4net.Util.SystemInfo.NotAvailableText = "NOT-AVAILABLE-TEXT"; ... thanks!!!